# How do you restart the network service on Fedora 30?

Tags: linux-networking, fedora

On previous versions on RHEL/Fedora, the `network` service could be controlled via init scripts and (later) via `systemctl`. After updating DNS settings, I want to restart the network service to bounce the interface and pickup the new DNS settings (and force NetworkManager to rewrite `/etc/resolve.conf`).

Using `systemctl`, I'm getting:

```
# systemctl restart network
Failed to restart network.service: Unit network.service not found.
```

Where'd the `network` service go and how do I restart the interface to pickup changes?

Comment: Services are now unit types, you can list all the available units by running the command `systemctl list-units`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `systemctl`, use NetworkManager, either via the GUI interface or the `nmcli` command-line.

### Command Line

1. List the network interfaces on the system (as root):

```
# nmcli device
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
eno1        ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1     
lo          loopback  unmanaged  --
```

Note the device name that you want to restart.

2. Then force the connection to reload:

```
# nmcli con reload eno1
```

(Substitute your device name for "eno1")

### GUI

1. Open the 'Settings' application in Fedora.
2. In the left column, scroll down to 'Network'
3. Toggle the blue switch off and back on again for the connection to want to restart.

Comment: This has been marked as the solution, but it doesn't work. I've done `nmcli con reload eth0`, but still cannot even ping google.com or do  a simple dnf update. Any ideas on what else to do?

Comment: @KhomNazid It will work to restart your connection, but it may not solve whatever the larger issue is in your case. Troubleshooting that is probably out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 3):

My internet flakes out often and `nmcli con reload ens33` doesn't fix it for me. I always have to run `systemctl restart NetworkManager` instead.

Comment: While `nmcli con reload x` seems more surgical this answer is more in line with my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to restart the server networking service.

```
# systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

or

```
# nmcli networking off
# nmcli networking on
```

Also `nmcli networking on` will help you in enabling your networking which might had been disabled somehow.

Comment: Things to consider: are you administering the server remotely? If so, will your current ssh connection drop if you execute `nmcli networking off`? If your current connection drops, you obviously cannot run the `nmcli networking on` to restore the connection.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It did the trick on Fedora 38.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

Edit your respective interface that needs troubleshooting

Add line 4 and don't forget to add the semi-colon at the end

```
[ipv4]
address1=192.168.100.71/24,192.168.100.1
dns-search=
dns=8.8.8.8;
method=manual
```

finally run

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

**If on remote host, the terminal will hang for a bit. Then you will be able to resolve domain names to IP addr's**

Comment: This is the correct answer for Fedora 30-35 distros and not the accepted answer.  That just turns on and off the adapter. This way controls the adapter.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

Worked on fedora

Comment: All `/sbin/service` and `/sbin/chkconfig` commands listed in the table continue to work on systemd-based systems and are translated to native equivalents as necessary. The equivalent of this would be `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`